# SQL Server Express ConnectionString not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-express

I am trying to connect to a local SQL Server Express database and I got it working inside a console application but now when I try to do it for a Windows service it doesn't work. I don't know what the problem is. The connection string that worked on the console application is below:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=BEN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=testDatabase;Integrated Security=True";
```

Any help is really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What error or exception do you get?

Comment: Datasource should be Data Source (with whitespace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using integrated security so the account that is running windows service is probably not configured on SQL Server. Windows service accounts typically have very little permissions.

You should either:

1. Change the account for the windows service that has access to SQL Server.
2. Or specify username and password in your connection string.

Comment: That was a mistake in my part, I did have a space in it - it still won't work.

Comment: Check this explanation now.

Comment: That makes sense, I will play around with it tomorrow, I can't imagine it would be anything else, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you Windows Service is running under account that doesn't have permissions on the database engine.

another possible issue Datasource. It should be Data Source (with whitespace)

Comment: That was a mistake in my part, I did have a space in it - it still won't work.

Comment: @user345453 what's the exception you are getting?

Comment: The windows service explanation by Szymon makes sense so i will play around with that when I wake up tomorrow, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the service account under which the service is running doesn't have appropriate permissions on the SQL Server Express database file or it doesn't have appropriate directory permissions.

Comment: Thanks! I will play around with it tomorrow.